# Check for equality of doubles in a list with a threshold

Tags: c#, math

I am working on a method wich should decide whether or not a curve has a nearly constant slope or not.

There are of course `x,y` points involved. What I did so far is dividing `y` of each data point by its `x` to get the slope of that data point. I store this slopes in a `List<double>`

I think so far I am on the right track (tell me please, if I am not!). Now it's time to decide about being dealing with a constant curve or not, so I ended up with the method below:

```
private bool IsConstantSlope(List<double> slopes)
{            
    var max = slopes.Max();
    var min = slopes.Min();
    var diff = max - min;

    return (diff > 0.01) ? false : true;        
}
```

So what I do here checking for maximum and minimum values of slopes and compare it to a custom threshold which I beleive is not good at all.

This method works good for perfectly constant sloped lines, but I want to give it some felexibility, I don't think comparing the difference of max and min values to a constant number is a good practice.

I will appriciate more ideas!

Comment: Why not use statistical functions like correlation?

Comment: hmmm no idea what are statistical functions :D first time heard it!

Comment: See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_and_dependence#Correlation_and_linearity

Comment: I agree with leppie, your approach is to simple depending on what you wan't to do. Your solution will give bad results in case of a local hike in the curve. But this might what you are after.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> There are ofcource x,y points involved. what I did so far is dividing
>   y of each data point by its x to get the slope of that data point. I
>   store this slopes in a List

Strictly speaking a **point** does not have a slope, what you are measuring here is the slope of the line that connects your point (x,y) and the point (0,0). So if you are doing this for an ordered set of points, then the notion of having a single line is not quite correct. You dont even have the set of slopes of lines that connect adjacent points. Also in your function

```
 return (max > 0.01) || (min < -0.01);
```

is better if your threshold is 0.01.

If what you really want is a line that fits or approximates the set of points then you first need to perform some kind of straight line regression to your data and test the gradient of this approximating line to see if it is within your threshold limits.

This might be a useful read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_linear_regression

Alternatively, you can order your points by their x value, then work out the slope between each consecutive pair (effectively generating a polyline) and store these in your list and *then* use your slope camparison function.

Comment: It's probably worth pointing out that the *correlation coefficient* that linear regression calculations produce is the measure of goodness-of-fit that OP seeks; the closer this is to 1 the better the straight line fits the points.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark That is true. Clearly a statistical approach makes more sense here but the OP stated that he is not familiar with such things. If tiny deviations needed detection I would personally fit a least-squares line using orthoganal distance regression and check the maximum absolute value of residuals to check for my acceptance/rejection criteria. Without more specific details of what accuracy is needed, there are a multitude of potentially acceptable ways to do this.

Answer (score 3):

I would design a recursive algorithm, working on the whole set of slopes. Considering only the min/max slopes doesn't tell anything about the whole curve.
First of all, I would establish which is the requirement that two slopes A and B must fulfill in order to determine a "constant slope". Then, I would consider the first (A) and last (B) values in your list: do the two values statisfy the requirement? No: no constant slope; Yes: subdivide the range (A,B) into two subranges: (A,M), (M,B) where M is the value equidistant, in the list, from A and B. Then you apply the same algorithm to the two subranges. The number of subranges depends on the accuracy you want to achieve.